# Ubuntu 20.10 5.8.0-1013-raspi aarch64 (Raspberry Pi 4) where are the w1 modules?

Tags: server, kernel, raspberrypi, 20.10, arm64

I've attempting to get a 1-Wire device to work on Ubuntu 20.10  linux-modules-5.8.0-1013-raspi and the w1-gpio, w1-them and wire modules are not installed.

Looking at the kernel source and the other builds I can see that linux-modules-extra-5.8.0(.*)generic for arm64.

However these 'generic' modules won't load into the raspi kernel (Exec failure).

I've also not succeeded in building a raspi kernel which is annoying..

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I've been investigating the early adopter 21.04 ubuntu release and that has the missing modules and they work.

My conclusion is thus that Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't support 1-Wire on the raspberry pi and that support is coming in 21.04.